# "To be present" is "vorliegen"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

Im having a difficult time with the word "vorliegen". It seems that in most cases, you can translate it as "to be present". I was wondering if the following translation would then work:

> I make sure that the right songs are in my playlist.
>   Ich sorge dafür, dass die richtige Lieder in meiner Playlist vorliegen.

Would this be correct? If not, what would you suggest in this context?

Comment: You may think of *vorliegen* as a word used predominantly by bureaucrats. It may be appropriate if you are a civil servant and write an official letter (although even in that case there would be friendlier forms of talking to people).

Comment: When you hear *vorliegen*, think of stuff lying on an evidence table: "The prosecution cites exhibit A!" Normal, everyday being-present is much more often expressed as *dasein*, *vorhanden sein*, *wir haben...*, *es gibt...* etc.

Comment: *Vorliegen* often means that something is present/available at a certain time. E.g. *Damit der Artikel gedruckt wird, muss er rechtzeitig vorliegen* = *For the article to be printed it must be present in time*.

Comment: And yet it has a bureaucratic and unfriendly touch to it. You would write *Der Artikel muss um 10 Uhr vorliegen* in some official instructions, but you would never talk like that to your colleague. Rather you would say: *Der Artikel muss um 10 Uhr da sein / hier sein / in der Redaktion sein / fertig sein.*

Comment: `vorliegen` *is* rather formal, but that doesn't mean, it's only used in bureaucratic context. A professional context is suitable as well.

Comment: The title may not be perfect, but Mark seems to understand what *vorliegen* means, he just wonders how widely applicable it is.

Answer (score 7):

> Ich sorge dafür, dass die richtige**n** Lieder in meiner Playlist vorliegen.

**Vorliegen** sounds very official.

> Beweise dafür lagen nicht vor. (*There was no evidence.*; police jargon)

These are far more common:

> Ich sorge dafür, dass **ich** die richtigen Lieder in meiner Playlist **habe**.
>
> Ich sorge dafür, dass die richtigen Lieder in meiner Playlist **drinstehen**.
>
> Ich sorge dafür, dass die richtigen Lieder **auf/in** meiner Playlist **sind**.
>
> Ich sorge dafür, dass die richtigen Lieder in meiner Playlist **drin sind**.

Same with *ich sorge dafür*. This can both sound very caring or very harsh, depending on the context. If you don't want to be this adamant about your playlist, better avoid that phrase.

> Ich **passe schon auf**, dass die richtigen Lieder in meiner Playlist drin sind.

*Don't worry, I take care the right songs are in my playlist.*

Comment: "auf meiner Playlist sind" klingt ... merkwürdig. Im Kontext "Playlist" empfinde ich "auf" generell als falsch. "Auf einer Liste" allgemein gesehen kann aber durchaus richtig sein.

Answer (score 1):

**vorliegen**

[synonyms](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/vorliegen.php) are vorhanden, dasein, existieren, etc.

In your case you want to express that something **exists**. A [synonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exist) for to exist is to **be**.

"**Be**" [translated](http://www.dict.cc/?s=be) into German is **sein**.

The correct [conjugation](http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-sein.html) for the third person plural is "**sind**".

> Ich sorge dafür, dass die richtige Lieder in meiner Playlist **sind**.

Answer (score 0):

`Vorliegen` is a special case of `vorhanden sein`=`to be present`: It has to lie (in a broad sense) somewhere (close). So, the verb may be applied to e.g.

- a file (paper version) lying on the desk: `Die Akte liegt vor.`
- a file (electronic version) being in a storage medium: `Die Playlist spielt nur ab, wenn die Musikdateien auf deiner Festplatte vorliegen.`
- a piece of evidence lying on the judges table: `Liegen denn Beweise für Ihre Behauptung vor?`

Answer (score 0):

You would not use the term "vorliegen" to describe  "dass die richtige Lieder **in** meiner Playlist vorliegen." If you're talking about something inside your play list, the correct verb is "sein" and "dass die richtige Lieder in meiner Playlist 'sind.'"

Vorliegen refers to something that is outside (whatever), but "lying close by," or "close at hand." For instance, you can use the term vorliegen to describe the relationship of a printer to your computer (lying separately but close at hand).